# find all descendants that has text in any element which starts with something in xml

Tags: xml, xpath

Hi I am trying to find all root nodes/descendants with any child node that has text, which starts with a namespace in this format: AAA__

```xml
<profile>
       <apexClass>
               <name>BPG__test</name>
       </apexClass>
        <field>
               <name>BPG__test</name>
       </filed>
</profile>
```

So I want to capture any of the root nodes i.e. apexClass, field that has a text node, which starts with BPG__c, but (BPG) could be any name and length. I am looking for examples in xpath to do this.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you looking for any text node which begins with any 3 capital letters followed by a double underline, or something else?

Comment: I am looking for any text node that starts with a pattern like ABC__, ABC can be any length followed by 2 underlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes there is at least one non-underline character in the text.

The code:

```
    <profile>
       <apexClass>
               <name>BPG__test</name>
       </apexClass>
        <field>
               <name>test</name>
       </field>
  <field>
               <name>c__test</name>
       </field>
  <field>
               <name>__test</name>
       </field>
</profile>
```

This xpath expression:

```
//*[name[string-length(substring-before(text(),'__'))>0]]/name()
```

Outputs:

```
apexClass
field
```

Comment: How would I capture the highest node and the node that has the text and capture it as a whole, so if field was the highest node that has BPG__test then i would want this whole node:

<field>
      <name>BPG__test</name>
</field>

Comment: and also if i did not know which element had the text?

Comment: and also i would not want to match on:

<field>Big_City__c</field>

Comment: @lodoss118 - As per SO policy, you should post these things as separate questions.